# How can I add some widgets to the position of siblings in the row at Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a discrete progress indicator similar to [percent indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) but in a discrete manner.

And I wanna add some guide widget or arrow at the position of the current progress position something like images. (It is not actually implemented, it is a view of widget inspector, but I wanna get the result of that image, top or bottom of the row.)

But, the problem is, how can I get the position of the child widget of the row and add some stacked widget to that?

[image: Tooltip at the position of sibling in the row]

```dart
class LinearDiscreteIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final int numTotal;
  final int numCurrent;
  final double? width;
  final double lineHeight;
  final double margin;
  final Color fillColor;
  final Color emptyColor;
  final Radius barRadious;
  final MainAxisAlignment alignment;
  final Widget? progressWidget;

  const LinearDiscreteIndicator({
    Key? key,
    required this.numTotal,
    required this.numCurrent,
    this.width,
    required this.lineHeight,
    this.margin = 2,
    this.fillColor = Colors.blue,
    this.emptyColor = Colors.grey,
    this.barRadious = const Radius.circular(2),
    this.alignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    this.progressWidget,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: lineHeight,
          width: width,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: alignment,
            children: List.generate(numTotal, (index) => index)
                .map(
                  (e) => Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: e == (numTotal - 1) ? 0 : margin,
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(barRadious),
                          color: e > numCurrent ? emptyColor : fillColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my current widget class code, but I'm not sure how can I enable a tooltip-like widget at the position of the current progress.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numCurrent = 10;
    var numTotal = 30;
    var itemWidth = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / numTotal);
    double containerWidth = 80;
    var positionLeft = ((itemWidth) * (numCurrent + 1)) - (containerWidth / 2);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: theme.colorScheme.background,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    left: positionLeft,
                    top: 10,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: const [
                          Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, child: Text("Container")),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp,
                                size: 24,
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      width: containerWidth,
                      height: 30,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: LinearDiscreteIndicator(
                      numCurrent: numCurrent,
                      numTotal: numTotal,
                      lineHeight: 4,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, I cannot get item width before drawing that. So, I wanna know proper way to handle this..

Comment: You have width of widget. width/numTotal = itemWidth